# can we dynamically get the id of a custom field?

Tags: urlhacking

I want to dynamically get the Id of a custom field to use it for url hacking in my javascript button.

```
var query = "SELECT Id,Name from Escalation__c where Escalated_CaseId__c={!Escalation__c.Escalated_CaseId__c} and '{!Escalation__c.Escalation_Status__c}='Active'";

var EscRecords = sforce.connection.query(query);
var records = EscRecords.getArray('records');

if(records.length>0)
{
var escalationId = records[0].Id;
var name = records[0].Name;
var baseUrl = "{!LEFT($Api.Partner_Server_URL_390,FIND('/services',$Api.Partner_Server_URL_390))}";
sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null,baseUrl+escalationId,true,name);
}
else
{
sforce.console.openPrimaryTab(null,baseUrl+{!$ObjectType.Escalation__c}+'/e/'+**CFcustomfieldIdhere**,true,name);
}
```

Is there a way to get this?

Answer (score 1):

This SOQL query will return a list of `FieldDefinition.DurableId`

```
SELECT DeveloperName,QualifiedApiName,NewUrl,
    (SELECT Id, DeveloperName, DurableId FROM Fields) 
  FROM EntityDefinition WHERE QualifiedApiName = 'Contact'
```

These `FieldDefintion` will look like (using Contact from my org)

```
DeveloperName=OpinionOfOurCompany, DurableId=Contact.00N30000000f0k7
DeveloperName=Primary_Support_Contact, DurableId=Contact.00N30000000xOCd
```

*Note the `__c` is stripped from the DeveloperName*